# Getting arraylist from the same class

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an arraylist and I want to use it in different things.

So is there a way to use it in different places? or I should write it in everywhere I want to use it?

If there is a way to use it in different places can someone show me?

```
public boolean checkAnswer(){
        ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
        switch(pos){
        case 0:
            answers.add("101");
            break;

        case 1:
            answers.add("42");
            break;

        case 2:
            answers.add("3212");
            break;

        case 3:
            answers.add("5554");
            break;

        case 4:
            answers.add("134");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

public void Answered(){
        input.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(31, 121, 0));
        input.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        input.setText(""); // I want to use the Arraylist there (setText of input).

        Button play_answer= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer);
        play_answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried putting ArrayList<String> answers as a global variable ?

Comment: @Tsunaze how? can you show me?

Comment: @Unihedron When I do this I get errors

Comment: input.setText(answer.get(index)); The Index points out the position in ArrayList.using getMethod(index) returns the value stored at index position .in your case values in arrayList are string because values are enclosed in "" . so you can directly set to TextView or EditText

Comment: @Unihedron I don't get what is in the ArrayList, I get null.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{
   private ArrayList<String> list;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test t = new Test();
      t.test1();
      t.test2();
   }

   public void test1(){
      list = new ArrayList<String>();
      list.add("hi");
   }
   public void test2(){
      System.out.println(list.get(0));
   }
}
```

That is how you use global variables. However your further experience with Android is going to be a painful one if you do not start with some sort of Java programming tutorial.

Also, referring to comment discussion under your question - if in this example you called test2() before test1() you would get an error, because the list would not be initialized. Again, refer to tutorials for more information.